# How to add the request body data in the post request for JMeter testing using Java code in the non-GUI mode?

Tags: java, jmeter

This is a Jmeter POST request in the form of a java code. I run this code to get no errors but I also get no response because my method of acting the request body data appears to be wrong.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
 import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.gui.HeaderPanel;
//import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
//import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent;
//import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument;


public class PostRequest {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    //JMeter Engine
    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/C:/Users/xxx");
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/C:/xxx");
    JMeterUtils.initLogging();
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    //JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
    HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

    //HTTP Sampler
    HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    httpSampler.setDomain("100.100.100.100");
    httpSampler.setPort(1111);
    httpSampler.setPath("/");
    httpSampler.setMethod("POST");
    httpSampler.addNonEncodedArgument("","{data:{ \"email\" : 
\"xx@gmail.com\",there are more values in the body"}]}","" );
    httpSampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);

    httpSampler.setFollowRedirects(true);
    httpSampler.setAutoRedirects(false);
    httpSampler.setUseKeepAlive(true);
    httpSampler.setDoMultipartPost(false);
    httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, 
HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
    httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, 
HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

    //Header Manager
    HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();

    headerManager.setName(JMeterUtils.getResString("header_manager_title")); 
    headerManager.add(new Header("abcs", "asdasd"));
    headerManager.add(new Header("dsferdg", "ertret"));
    headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, 
HeaderManager.class.getName());
    headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, 
HeaderPanel.class.getName());
    httpSampler.setHeaderManager(headerManager);

    //Loop Controller
    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setLoops(1);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
    loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler);
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, 
LoopController.class.getName());
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, 
LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
    loopController.initialize();

    //Thread Group
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setName("Sample Thread Group");
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, 
ThreadGroup.class.getName());
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, 
ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

    //Test Plan
    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, 
TestPlanGui.class.getName());
    testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new 
ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

    HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
    threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSampler,headerManager);

    //Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
    testPlanTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
    testPlanTree.add("loopController", loopController);
    testPlanTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
    testPlanTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);
    testPlanTree.add("headerManager", headerManager);

    Summariser summer = null;
    String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", 
"summary");
    if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
        summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
            }


    ResultCollector resultcoll = new ResultCollector();
    testPlanTree.add("resultcoll", resultcoll);
    resultcoll.setFilename("C:/Users/xxx");
    SampleSaveConfiguration saveConfiguration = new 
SampleSaveConfiguration();
    saveConfiguration.setAsXml(true);
    saveConfiguration.setCode(true);
    saveConfiguration.setLatency(true);
    saveConfiguration.setTime(true);
    saveConfiguration.setTimestamp(true);
    resultcoll.setSaveConfig(saveConfiguration);

    //Store execution results into a .jtl file, we can save file as csv also
    String reportFile = "C:/Users/xxx.jtl";
    String csvFile = "C:/Users/xxx.csv";
    ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
    logger.setFilename(reportFile);
    ResultCollector csvlogger = new ResultCollector(summer);
    csvlogger.setFilename(csvFile);
    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], csvlogger);

    //save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
    SaveService.saveTree(threadGroupHashTree, new 
FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\read.jmx"));

    // Run Test Plan
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();

    /*System.out.println("Test completed. See " + JMeterHome + slash + 
"report.jtl file for results");
    System.out.println("JMeter .jmx script is available at " + jmeterHome + 
slash + "jmeter_api_sample.jmx");*/
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

*I have used this code to configure the jmeter POST request and to add the body data but the request body appears to be `null` when I check the response.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should be adding arguments to `httpSampler`, and not to the `sampler`, something like:

```
HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
httpSampler.setDomain(xx);
httpSampler.setPort(xx);
httpSampler.setPath("xx");
httpSampler.setMethod("xx");
httpSampler.addNonEncodedArgument("body", body, "");
```

If you are building JMeter test from Java code using JMeter API check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) and [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src) repository for some snippets you could re-use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the above stated method before but when I check the response using Putty, the request body still comes to be null.

Comment: I need to see the full code, there is not enough information to troubleshoot the issue. So far I can recommend save request data into .jtl results file by setting the following [JMeter properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization): `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml` and `jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true` and inspect request details using [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), not sure what do you mean by "Putty"

Comment: I have edited the initial question and added the whole code.

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code (apart from missing escapes here `httpSampler.addNonEncodedArgument("","{data:{ \"email\" : \"xx@gmail.com\",there are more values in the body\"}]}","" );` and here `SaveService.saveTree(threadGroupHashTree, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\read.jmx"));`, it generates a HTTP Request sampler with the body data normally so the problem seems to be somewhere else.